# How to get items selected from checked listview on viewpager?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a viewpager in my program and on that I am displaying custom listview. On every viewpager swipe I am displaying the same listview but with differnt list items. I want to get all the items checked from all those listviews, when I click on the submit button.

But this submit button is not on my viewpager. Its quite complicated for me. Here is my main class code(I am just showing part of my code there are no errors in the code right now):

```
public class HotelMenu extends FragmentActivity implements CompletionListener {
    static final int ITEMS = 10;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    private NetworkTask networkTask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_menu);

        get_restaurant_menu();

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),HotelMenu.this);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//adapter for viewpager



        Button submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             //here I want all the items checked from the listview

            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my layout for this class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:background="@drawable/home_screen_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvRestNameForMenu"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/offers_text"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adpater for viewpager:

```
   public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        Context context;
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show list of maincourse items
                   // return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position, mainCourse);//pass viewpager page position and list to be displayed
                case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show list of soups

                    return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position,startersName,startersCost );
                default:// Fragment # 2-9 - Will show list
                    return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position, maincourseName,maincourseCost);
            }
        }
    }
```

and finally this is my fragment for displaying listview on viewpager:

```
public class ArrayListFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    int fragNum;
    String[] arr;
    ArrayList<String>item_name;
    ArrayList<String>item_cost;
    ListView lvsoups;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater1;
    View layoutView;

    public static final ArrayListFragment newInstance(int val, ArrayList<String> itemName, ArrayList<String> itemCost){

        ArrayListFragment list=new ArrayListFragment();
        //Bundle is used to use values and array passed through hotel menu class
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(2);
        bundle.putInt("val", val);
       bundle.putStringArrayList("itemName",itemName);
        bundle.putStringArrayList("itemCost",itemCost);
        list.setArguments(bundle);
        return list ;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieving this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //init passed values
        fragNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;

        item_name=getArguments().getStringArrayList("itemName");
        item_cost=getArguments().getStringArrayList("itemCost");
    }

    /**
     * to set view to the fragment activity
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list,
                container, false);


        lvsoups = (ListView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), item_name,item_cost);
        lvsoups.setAdapter(myAdapter);//set adapter to the list view
        return layoutView;
    }

    //adapter for the listview
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<String> itemName;
        ArrayList<String> itemCost;
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> item_name, ArrayList<String> item_cost) {
            this.context = context;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(item_name!=null)
            {
               // arr = new String[objects.length];
                this.itemName = item_name;
                this.itemCost=item_cost;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return itemName.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            int value;

            View menuRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_menu_list_item, null);

            TextView tvSoups = (TextView) menuRow.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuItem); //To set name of menu item, for example Corn Soup
            TextView tvPrice = (TextView) menuRow.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuPrice); //To set price of that item
            CheckBox cbQty = (CheckBox) menuRow.findViewById(R.id.cbMenuItem);
            Spinner spQty = (Spinner) menuRow.findViewById(R.id.spinnerQty);

            String[] quantity = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
            ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quantity);
            spQty.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

            tvSoups.setText(itemName.get(position));
            tvPrice.setText(itemCost.get(position));
            Log.e("arr", itemName.get(position));
            if (cbQty.isChecked()) {
                value = 1;
            } else {
                value = 0;
            }

            menuRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   // Intent intent=new Intent(SearchResult.this,RestMainActivity.class);
                   // intent.putExtra("Hotel_Master_Id",hotelMasterIdList.get(position));
                   // startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return menuRow;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

This is my hotel_menu_list_item.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="5">


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cbMenuItem" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"

       android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/tvMenuItem" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tvMenuPrice" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerQty"
      android:layout_weight="1"
         >
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `if (cbQty.isChecked()) ` ? Why would that be checked?

Comment: `R.layout.hotel_menu_list_item`. Please shoe xml file.

Comment: Which one is your problem?  Is it the submit button not visible?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid: I want the list of all the checked listview items on my submit button

Comment: You did not tell what `if (cbQty.isChecked())` does. How many pages are there used by your viewpager?

Comment: @greenapps If that cbQty is checked then I want that row details...so that I can add those in my database. I am just not getting if that item is checked how I would get those details that too on my Submit button click.  And my viewpager is dynamic.Number of pages is not fixed.

Comment: How can it be checked in getView? You just created a new menuRow and it is part of that menuRow.  There it is alway unchecked. So that code is useless. How many pages can there be?

Comment: @greenapps I just found a solution.And as I already told you my pages are dynamic. And I would like to tell you that no part my code is useless. I think you didnt even get my problem.